# Pressure sensor without using MEMS chips

Tags: sensor, analog, mems, pressure, medical

I'd like to figure out how to make a pressure sensor for very low cost (essentially disposable), mass produced piece of medical equipment.

The problem: this can't use **any parts which aren't already available in huge quantity**.  In other words only parts with > 100k and preferably > 1M in distributor stock.  This probably rules out the obvious approaches of using MEMS pressure sensors for cell phones (or does it? any super-high volume MEMS devices?).  Probably most specialty parts are out; commodity parts only (resistors, capacitors, generic op amps, generic transistors).  It is okay to fabricate components from raw materials (eg - a force sensitive resistor from conductive foam) if the materials are readily available.  It helps if all the parts used are extremely cheap (bom cost < $10).

What the sensor should do is sense pressure differences.  It needs to pick up changes of <1cmH2O (100 Pa) in pressure, and it needs to have response times <1 second.  For this 0.1 cmH2O precision and readings every 0.1 second are *great* specs.  The typical operating pressure is 0 to 40 cmH2O.  The physical form factor of what this connects to would be a short 20mm tube - as short as possible; 20mm x 20mm is good - with tapered connectors on both sides.  I assume this would need a mechanical component like a diaphragm or piston which is somehow interfaced to a PCB.

It's okay if this doesn't have a very accurate zero, and other specs like linearity, drift, offset, scale error are non-essential as long as roughly 1cmH2O changes can be detected between 0 and 40 cmH2O.  It is okay if each sensor needs an individual calibration.

Idea #1: diaphragm the position of which is read out using some version of capacitive touch - read out capacitance

Idea #2: diaphragm which compresses a force sensitive resistor made of anti-static foam - read out resistance

Idea #3: conductive diaphragm which touches a different number of conductive pads on the pcb depending on how far it's deflected - read out which pads are shorted together

Idea #4: conductive diaphragm the end to end resistance of which is read out depending on stretch

Bounty if rather than an idea, you build a working prototype.  Huge bounty if you do it within the next day or two.

Comment: You are a day late and a dollar short. A bunch of people thought we were going to be critically short of vents like a month ago. And if the curve had not deflected a bit, probably we would be by now (or soon) But there are serious companies with serious money jumping on it now. I don't think there will be any shortage. Maybe in countries like Brazil you might be able to help people. Not in the US though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mass production of sensors but, how come you are considering valid to use conductive foam as a sensor but discarding proper sensors in quantities less than 100k? I would think that it would be far easier to just take the dozens of sensors that are available in the low hundreds of thousands and adapt the interfaces/calibration. So instead of having to make a million conductive foam pressure sensors you just design a board that accepts different "proper" sensors.. no? Am I missing something?

Comment: @mkeith Yes, I am thinking of the rest of the world.  The US is not quite as oversupplied as you think - there are only about 30k full featured machines now, and supply will be limited to about 20-30k new production between now and end of May.  In the rest of the world, where the empidemic is just starting (South America?  Africa?  India??), it's oh so much worse than that, it's hard to describe it in words.  They probably won't do a lockdown; they'd probably have hundreds of thousands of critical cases at the same time

Comment: In that case liability is much less of a concern.

Comment: Dynamic range 0cmH2O to 40cmH2O, resolution 1cmH2O: Torricelli-style liquid-column barometer (inverted graduated cylinder or clear pipette sealed at top; fill upside-down; petri dish diaphragm). Wood stick inside pipette holds wires with insulation exposed at intervals to contact the H2O every cm or at preset alarm levels. Enclose with solvent-washable housing with inlet and this-side-up markings. 9V batt powered alarm/buzzer/LED board, not sure about exposed controls (due to electrical contact w/fluid media). Not corrosion resistant, not FDA, etc. Or cellphone video the water column height.

Comment: IMO the sensor approach is a wrong one to build quick and cheap breathing assistance machines. You have to look at the inhalating and exhalating process. Respirator (Dart Vador style masks with removable filters) have a valve reacting to air flow. I would look at this mechanism and find a way to apply connectors to it. When the air goes in some brass plates get in contact and send a signal. When air goes out other plates get in contact and send another signal. Think simple. Sensor ic's is for high grade certified devices which won't be built quickly nor cheaply.

Comment: Can the moderator also close all topics based on covid 19, before somebody reports that this platform is giving advice on how to make medical equipment without the proper standards! If find another user assisting people in this way again I will personally report you because this is not the platform for giving someone advice on something that is so serious. I have lost someone from this virus and these people who answered are definitely not helping the FDA or CDC to stop this virus!

Comment: @Joey I'm really sorry you lost someone.  FYI - I'm a medical device engineer; I've designed FDA cleared devices which are being used right now by the tens of thousands.  When you are at the hospital - someone very much like me made all those devices you see; and they probably asked people for advice, very possibly right on here.

Comment: @WesleyLee "So instead of having to make a million conductive foam pressure sensors you just design a board that accepts different "proper" sensors"  - That's a really good idea.  Turns out there are MEMS sensor families with a dozen parts where each part is available in 20-50k quantities.  Not quite drop in interchangeable, but close.  Thanks!

Comment: @AlexI I'm sorry but for all, I know you could be just using this platform for your own financial gain to implement this system and sell to vulnerable people. There is no way of authenticating your true identity or your assumed qualification! Your previous post as nothing to do with medical-related content, this therefore just adds to my suspicions on what your intentions are. And if you are medical engineering then why are you asking us, I am sure they as to be experts around you constantly due to this crisis!

Comment: @AlexI this shows, even more, you are doing something in the dark, why are you not consulting your own team on this matter? You say you have products approved by the FDA, this means you have a contact in the FDA, so why are you also not consulting them?

Answer (score 3):

Well, Digikey has some absolute pressure sensors with SPI and I2C interfaces, going for less than $1.50 and about 40,000 in hand.Resolution is 150 Pa.

But here's the catch on homemade pressure sensors - don't do it.

Look. Just don't. You're talking about the most critical sort of application - pressure fault alarm on a ventilator. This is NOT the place for jury-rigged sensors. If you try this sort of kludge, you will open yourself to grotesque levels of legal liability. And the fact that you are not manufacturing for profit is unlikely to save you.

Comment: Understood.  Legalities are a bit different outside the US, but - I think more to the point, you're right that a kludge is going to take time (and a number of iterations) to get right.  40k stock is just not gonna do it though.  I'm looking now and there are MEMS devices with close to a million stock.  Might be okay there.

Comment: @AlexI - Dude, you are missing the point. Homemade sensors suck. I don't care what sort of "ingenious" design you come up with, you're not going to get unit-to-unit consistency. And that will kill people in this particular case.

Comment: Do they suck more than literally no sensor?  Because that's what was probably gonna happen here.  You should see the disposable $1 plastic gauges that EMTs use all the time.  Okay, peace - I'm looking at MEMS which are available in large volume. I still do want to know how to do a kludge.

Comment: @AlexI "*Do they suck more than literally no sensor*" At 100Pa? Yeah they probably do due to the opportunity cost of wasting time on a sensor that's probably not going to work. Probably just better off using that time to build more ventilators. I don't know what pressure sensors ventilators traditionally use, but the pressure sensor I have for use in a UAV was made to be used in ventilators. It has a range of 500Pa, cost $140, and is a thermal type sensor which is basically a temperature sensor and heat source...but the devil is in the details.

Comment: The legal liability is off topic here. And off context because in the emergency, gov agencies, let alone developing country agencies, don't care much about that. The most important is to make clear to the users that this is not a certified device and that you can't be liable for malfunction. The "use at your own risk" statement. Of course it will better than no sensor.

Comment: Can the moderator please close and can people stop giving him help! Clearly he his in a state of desperation to help people no matter the cost. Which in case is killing people!

Answer (score 0):

The world-wide market for pressure sensors is well in excess of ten billion units annually.  I don't think finding a supplier with 1 million units available will be very difficult, there are likely tens millions of units surplused by the recent recession in addition to normal stock.

Comment: Okay - thanks!  Could you please let me know what some of the highest volume devices are?  It is possible a lot of this is normally ordered from the factory with the usual long lead times (12-16 weeks).  I'm just not seeing that much distributor stock.  I'll start calling up manufacturers next.

Comment: I don't think the ventilator market will be in the millions. It's rather in the tens of thousands, Not so many people need it.

Comment: @Fredled A lot of knowledgeable people think otherwise:  https://www.ventsforall.com/ "740,000 estimated ventilator deficit in the US alone".  That's was written by a dozen MDs - critical care and epidemiology.

Comment: @AlexI Let's hope you are wrong. So far in Europe ventilator shortage is in small numbers.